# SSAS Tabular, handle Dimension Blank Values

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular, dimensional-modeling

How do you handle blank values for SSAS Tabular?. 
Now i am using ssas model 1400. In SSas  Multidimensional, we had "unkown member". Can i have something similar using ssas Tabular?.

Comment: Tabular just reads tables. Why _wouldn't_ you be able to use unknown member instead of blank?

Comment: I want to replace the blank value for something like "no data"

Answer (score 4):

In SSAS Multidimensional you could control whether the unknown member was visible, hidden, or it throws an error if a fact points to an invalid dimension.

In Tabular if a fact row points to a dimension key that doesn't exist then a new blank row is automatically inserted into the dimension table and the fact row is tied to it.

If you aren't happy with this behavior then you need to change the data in SQL. For example, assign the problem rows a -1 dimension key and physically insert a -1 row into the dimension wording it however you like.

There is a good [blog post](https://www.skylinetechnologies.com/Blog/Skyline-Blog/November_2017/how-quickly-detect-tabular-referential-integrity) which outlines how you can detect relational integrity issues like this.

Comment: Thanks. can i replace de Blank value for something like "no Data"?

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoCabreraQuiroga only if you follow the instructions in my "if you aren't happy..." paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Greg explains the default behavior very clearly. I would add that i have yet come across a project where I dont add an "Unknown" record in most dimensions. Ideally the data will be very clean & there wont be any unknowns, but thats not reality unfortunately. Where this happens depends on your data, systems involved and the process surrounding them but it usually happens in one of a few places:

1. in the source system.
2. during ETL, check if an unknown record exists, if not, create it.
3. add one time during deployment/release.

Its almost always better to build in the behavior you want, instead of depending on defaults.